# How to put two labels in a table view cell one after another on iOS?

Tags: ios, uitableview, label, cell

I have two labels and trying to display both of them on a table view cell. But instead of being displayed one after another, the second label displays itself on the first one and the 1st one is never displayed...
How can I display the second label exactly after the first label? 
Here is my code :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *cell;
UILabel *label=nil , *secondLabel = nil;

cell = [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"] autorelease];
    //cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"] autorelease];

    label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero]; 
    [label setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    [label setMinimumFontSize:FONT_SIZE];
    [label setNumberOfLines:0];
    [label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE]];
    [label setTag:1];

    //[[label layer] setBorderWidth:2.0f];

    [[cell contentView] addSubview:label];

    secondLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [secondLabel setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    [secondLabel setMinimumFontSize:FONT_SIZE];
    [secondLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
    [secondLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE]];
    [secondLabel setTag:2]; 

    [[cell contentView] addSubview:secondLabel];    
}


//NSString *text = [items objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
int storyIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length]-1];
NSString *text1 = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"title"];  
NSString *text2 = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"summary"];

CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), 20000.0f);

CGSize size1 = [text1 sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
CGSize size2 = [text2 sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];    

if (!label)
    label = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:1];
if (!secondLabel)
    secondLabel = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:2];    

//[label setText:text1];
//[secondLabel setText:text2];

label.text = text1;
secondLabel.text = text2;

//cell.textLabel.text = text1;
//cell.detailTextLabel.text = text2;

[label setFrame:CGRectMake(CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN, CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN, CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), MAX(size1.height, 44.0f))];
[secondLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN, CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN, CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), MAX(size2.height, 44.0f))]; 

return cell;  }
```

and:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

int storyIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] - 1];
NSString *text1 = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"title"];
NSString *text2 = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"summary"];    

CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), 20000.0f);

CGSize size1 = [text1 sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
CGSize size2 = [text2 sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];    
CGFloat height = MAX(size1.height + size2.height, 44.0f);

return height + (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2);}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the same frame for both labels. Use different frames.

Answer (score 0):

You are never setting the frames for the two UILabels. For both label and secondLabel you are calling initWithFrame:CGRectZero so in both cases the origin.x and origin.y of their frames is 0.

secondLabel is marked as opaque by default which is why it is completely obscuring the first label.

To address this you should actually call setText: on the labels after they are added to the UITableViewCell. Once you have the size of label you can set the frame of secondLabel to be beneath that.